# XSLT: Regex to check for int

Tags: xml, xslt

i need data that is only in int format

when the node value comes in and starts with 00 then i need to change the 00 to 20

so when a non int value comes in, i can skip it

good:

```
<node>2322</node>
```

skip:

```
<node>232dasdf2</node>
```

Replace:

```
<node>0014</node>
```

-->

```
2014
```

Comment: matching integers is simple: "\d+". detecting leading zeroes can be done separately or in regexp: "^00(\d+)$". you could use something like this to replace: "^(00)?(\d+)$" -> "$2" where $2 is the second match. HTH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would work :

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
<root>
  <xsl:for-each select="//node">
    <xsl:if test=". castable as xs:integer">
      <node>
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '^0{2}([\d]+)$', '20$1')"/>
      </node>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</root>
```

**EDIT** : based on observations by @Michael Kay

Comment: Wanna see a simpler, pure XSLT 1.0 solution? :)

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Cool stuff :)

Comment: Note that \d matches all Unicode digits whereas [0-9] matches only ASCII (Western) digits. Take your pick.

Comment: You could also replace the test with `test=". castable as xs:integer"`. Note that in general it's better to get the content of an element using "." rather than "text()".

Comment: Updated answer. Why is it better to use .?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't know how to do this in XSLT but maybe this will be useful:

```
<?php
$data = Array("00123", "1234", "a1234sa");

foreach( $data as $d )
{
        if(preg_match("/^\d+$/", $d))
        {
                $d = preg_replace("/^(00)?(\d+)$/e", '("$1"=="00"?"20":"")."$2"', $d);
                echo "$d\n";
        }
}
```

HTH,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

**You don't need true RegEx capability for this and the problem can be solved easily in pure XSLT 1.0:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "n/text()[floor(.) = . and starts-with(., '00')]">

  <xsl:value-of select="concat('2', substring(.,2))"/>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="n[not(floor(.) = .)]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<t>
 <n>2322</n>
 <n>232dasdf2</n>
 <n>0014</n>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<t>
    <n>2322</n>
    <n>2014</n>
</t>
```

Comment: Can you explain what : n[not(floor(.) = .)]" do exactly?

Comment: Ah OK I saw that instead of node you use n. Was rather confused.

Comment: *I* am confused when someone uses "node" for an element name. I never use element names that are almost identical with XPath node-type tests.